# Installation Error

Tags: applications, motorola-droid, cyanogenmod

I'm getting the following installation error on a few of my apps when trying to update them:

"Installation error - Unknown Reason - 18"

Any suggestions?  I'm running CM6 on a Motorola Droid.

Comment: I've had the same issue on my HTC Desire (with the default OS install), with the error "Couldn't install on USB or SD card" when trying to update apps that had been installed to SD.  Removing `.android_secure/smdl2tmp1.asec` as per Jan Willem's post fixed this.  I'd suggest retagging this, since it doesn't just apply to cyanogenmod or rooted phones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apparently the problem is with apps installing to the SD card](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=782223).  Running the following command in the terminal fixed the problem for me:

```
su
rm /mnt/secure/asec/smdl2tmp1.asec
```

Answer (score 3):

Removing `smdl2tmp1.asec` is the solution, but because "su" will  lead to "permission denied" if you don't have a rooted phone, and because the `/mnt/secure/` appears to be empty, removing the file can be hard.

Alternatively you can do the following:

- connect the phone to a computer with USB
- mount the SD card as a disk drive
- remove `.android_secure/smdl2tmp1.asec`

Comment: +1 for the idea to mount SD as disk drive!